# How would I split a large set of tabular data into smaller relevant tables? (Not a DB Question)

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, math, scripting

I'm really hoping I can describe this question in an understandable way. This is a puzzle that I have not been able to begin to solve even though I (mostly) understand it. I'm just not sure where to start, and I'm really hoping someone out there can get me headed in the right direction.

I have a LARGE table of data. It describes relationships between objects. Let's say the Y-axis has items numbered 1-1000, and the X-axis has items 1-1000 also. If item #234 on the Y-axis is related to item #791 on X, there will be a mark in the table where the row and column cross. In some industries this is referred to an a Truth Table. One can, at a glance, see how many items in a system relate to each other. The marks in the table can help to identify trends and patterns.

Here's some other helpful stuff about the nature of the table:

- The full range of the number of relationships (r) for each item on either axis can be 1 <= r <= axisTotal.
- The X and Y axis will share common items, but each axis will also have items that the other axis does not.
- Each item will only exist once per axis. It can be on X and Y, but it would only be on each one 1 time.
- The total number of items on each axis will most likely NOT be equal. Each axis could have from 50 to 1000's of items.

The end result is that this is going to be a report that needs to be printed. We have successfully printed a table that had about 100-150 items on each axis on an 11in X 17in piece of paper. Any more than that and it begins to be so small it's unreadable.

What I am trying to do is split the super large tables into smaller tables, but related points need to stay together. If I grab item 1-100 on X then I would need each item they relate to from Y.

I've generated a number of these tables and, while the number of relationships CAN be arbitrary, I have never seen an item relate to all other items. So in real practice the range is more like 1 <= r <= (10% * axisTotal). If an item's relationships exceed this range, it can be split up into multiple tables, but that is not optimal at all.

At the end of the day I think we, and our clients, would be happy if a 1000x1000 item table was split into 8 to 10 printed pages of smaller, related tables.

Any guidance would be a great help! Thanks.

**---EDIT---**
One other thing worth noting, there will be no empty rows or columns in the table. Every item on both the x and y axis will relate to at least 1 item on the opposite axis.

**---EDIT---**
Here is an example of a small truth table that I'm describing: [image: Example Truth Table]. Every row and column has at least one relationship.

**---EDIT---**
May 18th, 2011
For what it's worth, I was moving pretty good on this project and I got pulled off for a couple of weeks. So it's going to a little while before I get back to this problem. But it is one that I will have to solve soon.

**---EDIT---**
July 11th, 2011
Bummer. Well, looks like I'm not going to be able to solve this problem right now. I was really hoping to be able to figure this out. Through discussion we decided to present the truth table in an Excel spreadsheet as an add-on resource to the main report. Excel 2007 and later will handle 1000's of columns which will more than suffice. Plus, we added some VBA which allows the viewer to double click on the column titles. This action will reduce the rows to only ones where there are interactions. Then it removes empty columns. In this way they can see a small sub-table based on the item they want to view, and can print it if they want.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a clustering algorithm that can group related things together into more manageable tables.  I don't know much about that, I can't really recommend more than searching for phrases like "machine learning" and "cluster analysis" and try to figure out what you need to know.

Comment: @btilly I found some stuff on clustering on Wikipedia thanks to your putting a name to the problem. I'm looking in it. If I come up with an algorithm to solve my problem, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer, I just want to try to visualize your data a little better. Does it kind of look like this?

```
        Alice  Bob  Charlie ... Zelda
Shoes     X            X
Hats            X                 X
Gloves                 X
...
Pants           X
```

**EDIT**

Is it a requirement to show the data in tabular format? Or could you just list each out? Something like:

- Alice

  - Shoes
- Bob

  - Hats
  - Pants
- Charlie

  - Shoes
  - Gloves
- Zelda

  - Hats

Or the other way:

- Shoes

  - Alice
  - Charlie
- Hats

  - Bob
  - Zelda
- Gloves

  - Charlie
- Pants

  - Bob

**EDIT 2**

Okay, I've made another larger truth table to hopefully get a better understanding of how you want to split things up:

```
   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
 1 x   x     x                             x
 2   x x     x             x         x     x
 3 x               x             x             x
 4         x             x     x
 5   x           x                 x
 6               x             x           x
 7   x             x             x
 8         x               x               x
```

For argument's sake lets just say that you can only fit 4 rows on a page (because I don't feel like typing out a giant table this early in the morning) so we're going to split this into two pages. First, it is important to show every row, right? Second, do you need to show columns that never have a value. For instance `Y` and `Z` never have a value for rows 1 through 8 in this table, can they be excluded from the report or do they still need to be there? Third, is order of the rows important?

If its not important to show completely empty columns then we could remove 10 columns from the table above and compress it down to:

```
   A B C E F H I L M O P Q R U V W
 1 x   x   x                 x
 2   x x   x       x       x x
 3 x           x       x         x
 4       x       x   x
 5   x       x           x
 6           x       x       x
 7   x         x       x
 8       x         x         x
```

Then if row order isn't important you can compress it further by taking an optimum row arrangement (not necessarily shown here). The two tables below have further been compress to 11 and 10 columns:

```
  A B C F H I M P Q R U
1 x   x x             x
2   x x x     x     x x
5   x     x       x
7   x       x   x

  A E H I L M O P U W
3 x     x       x   x
4   x     x   x
6     x       x   x
8   x       x     x
```

Am I going down a completely wrong path here? These are all just questions to help me better understand your data and output requirements.

Also, in all seriousness, is it an option to get larger printers/plotters? Also, is it an option to just generate a PDF and use Acrobat's print tile's option?

Comment: The general requirement is that it be tabular. A Truth Table is a common method to represent relationships in the industry we're targeting. The Truth Table is a portion of a much larger report that includes a view that breaks down the individual items.

Comment: @jwatts1980 I added some more questions above.

Comment: @Chris Haas For your new example, it looks pretty good. It also illustrates one of the weaknesses inherent to this approach, which is that several of the columns are duplicated in both tables. The "perfect" scenario would be one where the columns and rows aren't duplicated, but I think that mathematically that could be impossible in many cases. That said, I think the goal should be to minimize repetition. If there was a choice, for the data I'm representing, it would be better for the rows to be duplicated than the columns.

Comment: @Chris Haas I added an edit to my question related to the nature of the table. There will be no empty rows or columns in the "super table". Every item on both axes will relate to at least 1 item in the opposite axis.

Comment: @Chris Haas re: large printers and tiling... those are both options we've discussed. We even tried tiling the pages, but we just felt that the end result was not optimal. If it was between that and not having the table, it would be better to have it. But we felt that putting a good effort into trying to split the "super table" into smaller tables would be a better starting place than trying to get long term access to a plotter. Plus we want to make this as convenient as possible for our clients, and flipping through a short stack of papers seems better than unfolding one huge piece of paper.

Answer (score 0):

Last year I read an article at the Computational Biology PLoS journal ([www.ploscompbiol.org](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/)), that seems related to your problem.

In short, it describes a new approach when we already have a set of proteins and tabular data about their one-to-one interaction and we want to to group them so that interaction inside a group and interaction between two groups is either maximized or (this is the innovative idea) minimized .

If we plot the start data table with black for high and white for low interaction it looks randomly gray. The result table, after the calculations and rearranging is done (so grouped items are placed near one another), looks more like orthogonal areas of black and white.

The article: **[Protein Interaction Networks—More Than Mere Modules](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pcbi.1000659)**,

where there are also references to other older techniques for grouping this kind of data.

Comment: Wow, that article is pretty thick. I looked through some of the references, and haven't yet been able to find what I'm looking for. If the other avenues turn up empty, I'll dig a little deeper into this one.